# Refrigerator Fruit/Vegetable Bins

Tags: storage-method

Is there anything that makes the bins in the fridge particularly good (or bad) for storing fruits and vegetables. Previous refrigerators had a moisture control slide that altered humidity in the bins. My new fridge does not have this. I would rather store bread, meat and cheese in the bins and have my fruits and vegetables accessible on the shelves. Any reason not to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can store whatever you want in these bins - I regularly use one of mine to store bottled drinks.

However, depending where the cold air outlet is in your fridge, placing relatively fragile items such as fruits and vegetables on the shelves could cause them to freeze or form ice crystals internally, damaging the item.

Things like bags of apples or oranges tend to take up a lot of shelf space, so a bin helps contain them a bit by forcing them to stack vertically more-so than a flat shelf would.

So, pay attention to where the air vent is and your fridge overall temperature, as well as what's next to the items - otherwise it's OK to store fruits and vegetables on the shelf.

Answer (score 0):

The bins are actually called crisping or humidity drawers, so they do help with things like lettuces, celery and carrots.  They also control the gases the produce emits that can affect spoilage and over-ripening.  The use of two drawers is to keep fruit in one, and vegetables in another.  Their gases don't usually mix well and can cause spoilage.  Also, the drawers work better when full, so stock them up.

Storing produce on shelves for quick use should be fine, but in excess their gases can spread and affect other food.